# Decoding &amp; from all incoming requests to my node js app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Is there an easy way to detect and decode all encoded characters in any url coming to my node app ?

can it be done with a middleware that fetch and decode symbols like & ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/urlencode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `&amp;` shouldn't be in the URL that comes to your server.  If it is, someone is likely double-encoding something.

Second, you wouldn't want to decode the URL with middleware unless the usage of that decoded data is only used in that middleware.  What I mean to say is that you shouldn't modify the original URL, or other middlware may get confused.

Finally, JavaScript has `decodeURIComponent()` built-in.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent