# Why is Express converting &amp; to &amp%3B and how do I handle it?

Tags: node.js, express

I am running Express on NodeJS and I receive a request that looks something like `https://myserver.com/processCampaign?id=12345679&amp;campaignId=123456`.

Express converts that to `id=12345679&amp%3BcampaignId=123456`. So now I can't get the campaignId because I'm getting `'amp;campaignId':'123456'` in the query string instead.

So I'm wondering, do I have something set wrong in Express or should I be handling this differently?

Comment: Whats the output of your `req.query`?

Comment: { id: '12345679', 'amp;campaignId': '123456' }

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261982/decoding-amp-from-all-incoming-requests-to-my-node-js-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I have no control over the inbound request (which is incorrect), I have no choice but to handle it on my side. I've read that the inbound URI is most likely incorrect because it is being double-encoded on their side.

Here's the solution I have come up with:

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.query).replace('amp;campaignId', 'campaignId'))`

If anyone has a better idea I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In express multiple queries are seperated with '&'. You don't need to use 'amp;' before the next query string. In your case, the url below will give you both the id and campaignId query.

```
 https://myserver.com/processCampaign?id=12345679&campaignId=123456
```

If you log req.query now, you will get

```
 { id: '12345679', 'campaignId': '123456' }
```

Comment: I don't have control over the req that the server receives so there is nothing I can do about the URI